# How to install latest Mate DE 1.14 in Ubuntu Mate 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

Ubuntu Mate 16.04 has Mate DE 1.12. I wish to update to latest version 1.14. Please can somebody guide.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it doesn't have .deb versions. You will have to download the package in another form and install it manually.
I am copying the original answer from here:[Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=220429)

> Ok.. We have now Mate 1.14 released, but we don't have (jet) the debs
>   in repos. But there is not a problem.. We can install it by hand, by
>   compiling it.
>
> Note: This is just an example how to install the one package! To have
>   entire desktop You must install entire suite!Just repeat the steps for every package and you're done.
>
> --- Before we begin -> sit down, make a coffee, calm down and make a SYSTEM BACKUP just in any case!
>   --- I am not responsible for any damage done to your machine/system! All You do, You do at your own risk! If You don't know what you're doing, don't do that! Better wait for the packages in the ppa!
>   --- Ok.. Download the package here (and/or all packages you need/want):
>   http://pub.mate-desktop.org/releases/1.14/mate-desktop-1.14.0.tar.xz
>
> Or here:
>   http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/Window-Managers/MATE-84165.shtml#download
>
> Entire release is here (recommended download source):
>   http://pub.mate-desktop.org/releases/1.14/
>
> And here: http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/status:1.14
>
> Then unpack (one at a time) and install all the necessary
>   dependencies:
>
> Code: Select all and then type `sudo apt-get install gtk+-2.0`
>
> Next go to the already unpacked directory, RPM in it and choose "open
>   in terminal".
>
> Now type a command:
>
> Code: Select all and then type `./configure`
>
> Then:
>
> Code: Select all  and then type `make`
>
> And at the end:
>
> Code: Select all and then type `sudo make install`
>
> Wait a moment, until it installs and do the machine reboot.
>
> If by the "./configure" some errors/infos about missing dependencies
>   appears, then just simply install them and do the ./configure again.
>   All should be ok now.
>
> If terminal shows something up about missing or wrong "dconf" version
>   then do:
>
> Code: Select all and then type `sudo apt-get install libdconf-dev`
>
> And try again ;) This helped me and the installation ended without any
>   other problems.
>
> That same installation schema apply for all other downloaded packages.
>
> Enjoy! :)